# AngularJs - getting undefined object when passing parameters through ui-sref

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Hi I am very new to angularjs and here is my code

html

```
<table ng-table="tctrl.tableEdit" class="table table-striped table-vmiddle" show-filter="true">
  <tr ng-repeat="w in $data"  ng-class="{ 'active': w.$edit }">
    <td data-title="'Company name'" filter="{ 'cl_company_name': 'text' }" sortable="'cl_company_name'">
      <a ui-sref="clients.client-detail({ clientId: w.cl_id })"><span ng-if="!w.$edit">{{ w.cl_company_name }}</span></a>
      <div ng-if="w.$edit"><input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="w.cl_company_name" /></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

controller.js

```
.controller('TabsClientCtrl', function ($scope, $window, $stateParams) {

   $scope.clID = $stateParams.clientId
   alert($scope.clID)
})
```

state.js

```
.state ('clients', {
    url: '/clients',
    templateUrl: 'views/common.html'
})

.state('clients.client-detail', {
    url: '/client-detail',
    templateUrl: 'views/client-detail.html',
    resolve: {
         ...
    }
})
```

when I click on company name in td I get alert with undefined. Is that correct way to pass parameters using ui-sref?

Comment: what do you have in `w` and add your state configuaration to the question.

Comment: yes you have to issues, please check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change your route to

```
.state('clients.client-detail', {
    url: '/client-detail/?clientId',
    templateUrl: 'views/client-detail.html',
    resolve: {
         ...
    }
})
```

or

```
.state('clients.client-detail', {
    url: '/client-detail/:clientId',
    templateUrl: 'views/client-detail.html',
    resolve: {
         ...
    }
})
```

based on your requirement

Comment: Can you tell me the difference between both of them?

Comment: When using the first approach "clientId" will be optional. For 2nd approach "clientId" should be concatenated with URL

Comment: Okay got it. Thank You! @Vinoth Rajendran

Answer (score 1):

There are two thing to change in your routes,

**1) Add the id parameter to the route url**

`url: '/client-detail/:clientId',`

This `:clientId` is required to tell `ui-router` that you are sending some parameter via the route.

**2) Add the controller:**

`controller: 'TabsClientCtrl`

The controller is required as you are using those parameters in that controller.

```
.state ('clients', {
    url: '/clients',
    templateUrl: 'views/common.html'
})

.state('clients.client-detail', {
    url: '/client-detail/:clientId',
    templateUrl: 'views/client-detail.html',
    controller: 'TabsClientCtrl,
    resolve: {
         ...
    }
})
```

Comment: but you needed the controlle, or have you given it in the view?

Comment: Yes it is in the view.

Comment: okay, if it is in the view, no need of controller in the route.